# is it worth catching an Exception just to close a stream and reset a CharsetDecoder?

Tags: java

My understanding is that closing streams in Java is recommended, but not even close to a "requirement". Likewise, it's a good idea, but not near a requirement, to reset a *CharsetDecoder* after you are done using it.

Throwing the exception makes the method look clean and very readable. Catching the exception might be "recommended", but it adds a little clutter to the method. So, on a professional programming team, would you really "catch and close/reset"? Is it that important? Here, I preferred to just throw it:

```
<!-- language: Java -->
    public static String[] grabData(URL url, CharsetDecoder dcdr) throws Exception {  

        List<String> dump = new ArrayList<String>();
        dcdr.reset();

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        BufferedReader bufrdr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), dcdr));
        while (dump.add(bufrdr.readLine())) { }

        bufrdr.close();
        dcdr.reset();

        return dump.toArray(new String[0]);
    }
```

Comment: Pretty sure there was a clause in the java specs that says something like "recommended means you really should do it" and how it's not a requirement because you don't HAVE to do it if absolutely don't want to.

Comment: You don't catch an exception to clean up. You use a finally block. That's what they're for.

Comment: @JB Nizer I've heard of finally blocks, but I thought the jvm could not guarantee that they would always be called. I will definitely check them out again. thank you.

Comment: @eddie_j You are confusing finalizers and finally blocks. They are two different concepts.

Comment: The JVM guarantees it. The only way for a finally block to not be excuted is an infinite loop before the finally block, a JVM crash, or a System.exit() call. You're confusing finally with the finalize() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding is incorrect. It is indeed a requirement to close open streams, because they acquire native OS resources that are not freed when the object goes out of scope.

As far as throwing exceptions, *someone* has to catch it and deal with it. And you should **never** throw `Exception` like that -- throw the specific exception types that may occur.

Comment: What I'm saying is that when a programmer has schedules to meet and product to get out the door, do they really nit-pick over exception handling? Seriously, I need to accelerate to a deadline. Fine-tuning exception handling is theoretically nice, but currently in my way. A lot of people must also have had this problem.... Well, what about resetting the decoder? I don't think resetting it is my responsibility? But, it would absolutely reduce the potential for bugs. Should I catch an exception just to do a reset?

Comment: Your schedule is going to go out the door when you find it impossible to debug your app due to shoddy exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

Open streams might accumulate and eventually exhaust operating system resources. Ditto with other resources, which can be critical in long-running programs. So it is a very good habit to get into.